# How to Add UI to installer for wix v4 (HeatWave for VS2022 FireGiant)

Tags: visual-studio, wix, windows-installer, wix4

I recently started working on wix v4 for creating msi installers for our applications, currently am facing issue regarding adding ui in installer. I am using the visual studio plugin for wix v4 (HeatWave for VS2022 FireGiant). There is no apparent method of help document to do so, previous ones were made for wix v3 and I am not sure how add the ui sdks with the v4 project in visual studio.

I also tried adding wix library reference via visual studio (right click project, add, wix library reference) but that page is also empty.

[image: Wix Library Reference]

I also tried adding the ui .wxs file as per the following guideline [How To: Use WiX Extensions](https://wixtoolset.org/docs/v3/howtos/general/extension_usage_introduction/), I browsed to the directory of he wixuiextension.dll and tried to add it but failed
[image: DLL Adding error]

Answer (score 1):

Okay So I dig some more digging turns out there does exists a document for this particular problem, [How to Add UI](https://wixtoolset.org/docs/tools/wixext/wixui/#dialog-sets), this basically requires us to use our NuGet package manager in Visual Studio and add the following package "WixToolset.UI.wixext", after adding this we need to add the reference schema to our project with out primary one as show below

```
<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs"  xmlns:ui="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/ui">
```

Afterwards you can add one of the prebuilt UI's in your project as per the docs,
[image: Ui Options]